# Double the width of the ibeam cursor in Linux Terminals?

Tags: linux, terminal

I would like to use the `ibeam` `|` cursor in my terminal, but is it is very narrow and hard to spot especially in the `vim` editor. Is it possible to increase the width or probably specify a Unicode character instead?

I am using the `termite` terminal emulator  which is based on VTE.

For example in the Sublime Text editor, it is almost double in size and I think that is ideal for me. Need to try it out though.

Comment: Which terminal emulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For terminal emulators based on recent versions of `VTE` (e.g. `gnome-terminal`, `mate-terminal`, `xfce4-terminal`, `terminator`, `tilix` and a few more), place something like this in your `.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file:

```
vte-terminal, VteTerminal {
    -GtkWidget-cursor-aspect-ratio: 0.2;
}
```

You'll need to quit and restart the terminal emulator process (qiut all its windows at once).

Comment: Superb. I was about to delete this question as I thought no one would know it ;-).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for Konsole. 
How do I know on what a terminal emulator is based?

Comment: `ldd /path/to/your/terminal/emulator` and look for `libvte`. Or check the package's dependencies. Or the source code, the webpage etc. Konsole is not VTE-based.